# Running count but reset on some column value in select query

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to achieve a running value, but condition is reset on some specific column value.

Here is my select statement:

```
with tbl(emp,salary,ord) as
(
   select 'A',1000,1 from dual union all
   select 'B',1000,2 from dual union all
   select 'K',1000,3 from dual union all
   select 'A',1000,4 from dual union all
   select 'B',1000,5 from dual union all
   select 'D',1000,6 from dual union all
   select 'B',1000,7 from dual
)
select * from tbl
```

I want to reset count on emp B if the column value is B, then count is reset to 0 and started again increment by 1:

```
emp  salary  ord  running_count
A    1000    1       0
B    1000    2       1
K    1000    3       0
A    1000    4       1
B    1000    5       2
D    1000    6       0
B    1000    7       1
```

Here order column is **ord**.

I want to achieve the whole thing by select statement, not using the cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to define groups were the counting takes place.  Within a group, the solution is `row_number()`.

You can define the group by doing a cumulative sum of `B` values.  Because `B` *ends* the group, you want to count the number of `B` *after* each record.

This results in:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by grp order by ord) - 1 as running_count
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when emp = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by ord desc) as grp
      from tbl t
     ) t;
```